# What is the best option to do a SQL in this case

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL sentense:
`SELECT aps.*,(SELECT name FROM brands WHERE id=aps.brand) as brand FROM applications as aps`

And this another:
`SELECT aps.*,brd.name as brand FROM applications as aps INNER JOIN brands as brd ON aps.brand=brd.id`

The query result for both are equal, so I'm guessing there isn't any difference between the two. but what about the optimization?

Comment: use `explain your query` in mysql and this will tell u more..

Comment: a join with an index is better than your co-related query,a co-related subquery will run forech related record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first query, SQL Server will execute the subquery for each record to get the right value you want to display (name), but in the second query using join statement you will get a optimised result using the performance of the database engine. (You will notice a very very big difference if you have a lot of datas in your tables). I recommand using JOIN statement and create indexes in the used columns.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

The queries are not equivalent, they will produce different results in the case in which `aps.brand` does not match an `id` value in the `brands` table or where `aps.brand` is NULL.  They would be equivalent if you changed `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in the second query.

How the queries would be optimized is a decision of the query optimizer and no one who isn't intimately familiar with the internals of the query optimizer is in a position to guess what will happen.  If you're concerned about the optimization path, most SQL engines have an EXPLAIN feature that will tell you exactly how the query is being planned and executed.

I think it's fair to say that 99% or more of SQL programmers would prefer the version with the `JOIN` over the internal correlated query, even if the optimizer plans them out exactly the same way.